# Can maple use Divergence theorem during simplification?

Tags: symbolic-math, maple, calculus

I have some multivariate integral manipulation that I'd like to verify with Maple, but I can't seem to get it to invoke Divergence theorem (a.k.a. Gauss's theorem; special cases of Stokes' theorem; generalizations of integration by parts, Green's theorem).

For example, consider the [Dirichlet energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_energy):

E(v) = ∫ ∇v.∇v dA = -∫ v ∆v dA + ∮v ∇v.n ds

Suppose I'd like to verify the application of Divergence theorem, I could try defining both sides of the equality (`Dirichlet` and `Dirichlet2`) over the unit square and checking whether their difference is 0:

```
with(LinearAlgebra):
with(VectorCalculus):
Lap := (v) -> Divergence(Gradient(v,[x y])):
boundary := (v,w) -> \
  eval(int(DotProduct(Multiply(w,Gradient(v,[x,y])),< 0,-1>),x=0..1),y=0) + \
  eval(int(DotProduct(Multiply(w,Gradient(v,[x,y])),< 0, 1>),x=0..1),y=1) + \
  eval(int(DotProduct(Multiply(w,Gradient(v,[x,y])),<-1, 0>),y=0..1),x=0)+ \
  eval(int(DotProduct(Multiply(w,Gradient(v,[x,y])),< 1, 0>),y=0..1),x=1):
Dirichlet2 := (v,w) -> \
  -int(Lap(v)*w,x=0..1,y=0..1) + boundary(v,w);
Dirichlet := (v,w) -> \
  int(DotProduct(Gradient(v,[x,y]),Gradient(w,[x,y])),x=0..1,y=0..1):
simplify(Dirichlet(v(x,y),w(x,y)) - Dirichlet2(v(x,y),w(x,y)),size);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't return the desired:

```
0
```

instead, just a long sequence of unevaluated interior and boundary integrals.

I can of course verify this for explicit functions:

```
Dirichlet(x^2+y^4,x^2+y^4) - Dirichlet2(x^2+y^4,x^2+y^4);
```

does return

```
0
```

(any of course will for any other function). But is there anyway to tell Maple to invoke Divergence theorem internally? Then I can verify the above (and my actual, more complicated expressions) fully symbolically. Or, if not, is there some way I can rearrange my input to help maple figure this out?